# Step by step procedure to lock the record for edit and delete based on status in salesforce

Tags: apex

If status is approved , I want to lock the record for edit/delete. Whats the best way to do this trigger,workflow rule or validation

Comment: What about an [Approval Process](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Approval_Processes)?

Comment: @sfdcfox I think he is referring after approval.

Answer (score 1):

As of available options you have Trigger will be best suited for you.

Because you can't stop update or delete from Workflow.

And Validation rule will not work in case of delete.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account(before update, before delete) {

for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
  if((acc.status__c =='Approved' && acc.status__c == Trigger.oldMap()get(acc.Id).status__c) || Trigger.oldMap()get(acc.Id).status__c =='Approved')
     acc.addError("You can't update/Delete this record.')
}
```

You can use this sample code as reference but note that this **might not cover** all your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

**[Set Approval Process Locks and Unlocks with Apex Code](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm)**

> New lock() and unlock() methods in the System.Approval namespace let
>   you lock records by passing in record IDs or sObjects. Previously, you
>   could set approval-process locks and unlocks only through the
>   Salesforce user interface. To enable this feature, from Setup, enter
>   Process Automation Settings in the Quick Find box, then click Process
>   Automation Settings. Then, select Enable record locking and unlocking
>   in Apex.
>
> Salesforce admins can edit locked records. Depending on your approval
>   process configuration settings, an assigned approver can also edit
>   locked records. Locks and unlocks that are set programmatically use
>   the same record editability settings as other approval-process locks
>   and unlocks. Record locks and unlocks are treated as DML. They’re
>   blocked before a callout, they count toward your DML limits, and if a
>   failure occurs, they’re rolled back along with the rest of your
>   transaction. To change this rollback behavior, use an allOrNone
>   parameter.